# order by result search?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

if have in database words `nice car, nice, nice, nice car` and we searched word `nice`: how can **ORDER BY** (listed) those like : `nice, nice, nice car, nice car` or if searched word `nice car` **ORDER BY**(listed) like: `nice car, nice car, nice, nice` ?

- words in database : `nice car`, `nice`, `nice`, `nice car`
- nice => `nice`, `nice`, `nice car`, `nice car`
- nice car => `nice car`, `nice car`, `nice`, `nice`

my query:

```
$find = $this->input->post('find');
    $where  =   "name LIKE '%$find%' OR 
            star LIKE '%$find%' OR
            address LIKE '%$find%'";
$query = $data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
        FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM my_table
        WHERE 
            $where
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT $offset, $coun_page       
        ) t,
        (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");
```

Comment: If you search for the word 'nice car' the select statement will not return any records that are just 'nice'

Answer (score 5):

MySQL is not a search engine. I'd highly recommend using something that actually is for this task (e.g. Sphinx, Solr, or Lucene).

Comment: `Sphinx, Solr, or Lucene` -> what is these? Please give me explain further, and examples

Comment: Go to the address bar of your browser and type in `www.google.com`, then a magic box will appear near the middle of the screen.  Type `Solr` in there and click search.  It's amazing what technology can do today.